# How to get the object in desired format from DynamoDb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have `ASP.Net Core` (`C#`) application with `DynamoDb` as datbase Below is my how my function looks like:-

```
public async Task<object> GetEvent(string eventId)
    {
        try
        {


            var req = new QueryRequest()
            {
                TableName = _tableName,
                KeyConditionExpression = "EventId = :v_Id",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                {
                    { ":v_Id", new AttributeValue()
                    {
                        S = eventId
                    } },
                    {
                        ":v_isDeletedFlag",new AttributeValue()
                        {
                            BOOL = false
                        }
                    }
                },
                FilterExpression = "IsDeleted = :v_isDeletedFlag",
                Limit = 1,
            };
            var res = await _dynamoClient.QueryAsync(req);

            if (res.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                return res.Items;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No such event found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But the above method returns the object as below:-

```
[
{
 "CreatedOn": {
  "b": null,
  "bool": false,
  "isBOOLSet": false,
  "bs": [],
  "l": [],
  "isLSet": false,
  "m": {},
  "isMSet": false,
  "n": null,
  "ns": [],
  "null": false,
  "s": "Friday,16 August 2019 14.33.35",
  "ss": []
},
"IsAlcoholAllowed": {
  "b": null,
  "bool": false,
  "isBOOLSet": true,
  "bs": [],
  "l": [],
  "isLSet": false,
  "m": {},
  "isMSet": false,
  "n": null,
  "ns": [],
  "null": false,
  "s": null,
  "ss": []
},
"Description": {
  "b": null,
  "bool": false,
  "isBOOLSet": false,
  "bs": [],
  "l": [],
  "isLSet": false,
  "m": {},
  "isMSet": false,
  "n": null,
  "ns": [],
  "null": false,
  "s": "Hello Events",
  "ss": []
},
"Title": {
  "b": null,
  "bool": false,
  "isBOOLSet": false,
  "bs": [],
  "l": [],
  "isLSet": false,
  "m": {},
  "isMSet": false,
  "n": null,
  "ns": [],
  "null": false,
  "s": "Test Event Mumbai",
  "ss": []
}}]
```

But what I want is the object with key & value as below

```
[
{
 "CreatedOn":  "Friday,16 August 2019 14.33.35",
 "IsAlcoholAllowed": false,
  "Description": "Hello Events"
}]
```

How can I get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly,
you're querying data using Dynamo's [Low-Level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-intro.html#dynamodb-intro-apis-low-level) programming model which is why you're getting a verbose JSON describing each attribute.

If you'd like more control over your response how about using DynamoDB's [Object-Persistence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-intro.html#dynamodb-intro-apis-object-persistence) programming model?

Define a model representing your document:

```
[DynamoDBTable("Events")]
public class Event
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]   
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public bool IsAlcoholAllowed { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Then query via:

```
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

var filter = new QueryFilter();
filter.AddCondition(Model.HashKey, QueryOperator.Equal, 123);

var events = await context.FromQueryAsync<Event>(new QueryOperationConfig
{
    Select = SelectValues.AllAttributes,
    Filter = filter
});
```

You can then pass a list of this model in a JSON parser which gets you closer to your target data structure.

Comment: Every event can have different properties, so can't define the Event